# Single cartfile to specify and install dependencies for multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

Is there a way to write a single cartfile which can be used to install the dependencies required for multiple targets. This can be achieved when we're using Cocoapods as shown below:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

def rx_swift
    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 4.0'
end

def rx_cocoa
    pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 4.0'
end

def test_pods
    pod 'RxTest'
    pod 'RxBlocking'
    pod 'Nimble'
end


target 'CleanArchitectureRxSwift' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  rx_cocoa
  rx_swift
  pod 'QueryKit'
  target 'CleanArchitectureRxSwiftTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    test_pods
  end

end

target 'CoreDataPlatform' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  rx_swift
  pod 'QueryKit'
  target 'CoreDataPlatformTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    test_pods
  end

end

target 'Domain' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  rx_swift

  target 'DomainTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    test_pods
  end

end

target 'NetworkPlatform' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    rx_swift
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'RxAlamofire'

    target 'NetworkPlatformTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        test_pods
    end

end

target 'RealmPlatform' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  rx_swift
  pod 'RxRealm', '~> 0.7.1'
  pod 'QueryKit'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.10'
  pod 'Realm', '~> 3.10'

  target 'RealmPlatformTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    test_pods
  end

end
```

Please let me know whether can we achieve similar thing while using Carthage? i.e. by writing all the dependencies needed for all targets in a single cartfile and then installing them using carthage?

Why I want to do this is, I feel that as we go on adding dependencies to different targets(frameworks) used in the application, it'd be easy to maintain if we have all the dependencies listed in a single cartfile.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have moved to CocoaPod recently(from Carthage) And I believe it is so much easier to get it work with different targets. In addition, no manual framework/binary/script is needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in Carthage, and [will probably never be supported](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1692#issuecomment-298891842).

You could list all the dependencies in a single Cartfile, but you'll still have to manually select and add them to your target's `linked frameworks and libraries`.